# POST request to .net core web api from Chrome is not working

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ionic-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on a .net core web api project and this block giving me nightmares. I'm trying to send request from ionic-angular to .net core project. GET request is working perfectly. But the POST request is not. when i try to test the project in chrome, it says net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET to a OPTIONS request. I understand Chrome send a preflight OPTIONS request before my real POST request. But that is the problem. I tried to handle that OPTIONS request with a Middleware like this

```
  

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

    namespace A.Middlewares
    {
        public class OptionsMiddleware
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
            private IHostingEnvironment _environment;

            public OptionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment environment)
            {
                _next = next;
                _environment = environment;
            }

            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(context);
                await this._next.Invoke(context);
            }

            private async void BeginInvoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost:8100" });
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" });
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost:8100" });
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" });
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
                }

            }
        }

        public static class OptionsMiddlewareExtensions
        {
            public static IApplicationBuilder UseOptions(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
            {
                return builder.UseMiddleware();
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is still not helping. If there is any trick around that, enlighten me!

Comment: What is the URL of the hosting webpage? What is the URL you are attempting to POST to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For that you have to install one extension in your chrome browser, which sent Cross-Origin Request to the server. Url is given bellow.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: there are many other Cross-Origin Request extension also available in other browser also...

Comment: Just beware that doing so compromises the security of your browser

Comment: Yes i know that but many extension are providing on off switch as well, when we need to test any thing in ionic or any cross browser request at that time we ON the switch..

Answer (score 1):

The reason Chrome is sending `OPTIONS` is because your .net server is located at another URL (domain) than the webpage (component) that is making the post. This is to protect you from Cross Origin type of attacks using CORS - Cross-Origin Request Sharing.

You can enable CORS in your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
          // All the other things here
           if (env.IsDevelopment()) // For development only, we allow CORS from anywhere.
            {
                app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials().Build());
            }
         }
```

You would need to install this package: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`.

Some further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: This might be the same function to my codes above. I don't think the problem is not concerned with headers. But that might be to handle the options method. How can i return 200 to OPTIONS method and move to next request? That is the trick. Please check my code above.

Comment: It is not enough to return 200 to CORS; you have to specify the allowed methods and allowed headers. Which is why it is easier to use the microsoft provided library than code it yourself...

Comment: Man, you got the point. I put your code inside my Startup.cs but still not fix it. You may see I have already specified allowed methods and headers in my code above. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Need add below few lines of code in global.aspx of WebAPI

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```